# Qt: How to figure out the minimum size of rich text inside QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit which I initialize as follows:

```
QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
textEdit->setReadOnly(true);
textEdit->setHtml("<p style=\"color:red; font-family:'Courier New';\">Raw Header</p>");
textEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
textEdit->append("<p style=\"font-family:'Courier New'\">00000000<br />00000000<br />00000000<br />00000000</p>");
textEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

This textEdit is later added to a QGridLayout, and on that layout it looks like this:

[image]

I want to resize it to its minimum size while the text is still visible without having scrollbars.
Every suggested solution I could find made the assumption that the QTextEdit is already visible which is not the case here.
I want to predetermine the width/height before the `show()` is called by the layout on that object.

Some more things I've tried:
[`QTextDocument::size()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#size-prop)
[`QTextDocument::idealWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#idealWidth)
[`QTextDocument::pageSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#pageSize-prop)
[`QTextBlockFormat::lineHeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html#lineHeight-1)  (by iterating on all QTextBlock in the QTextDocument)

All return zero because the QTextEdit and the text inside are not rendered yet.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate rendered text dimensions using `QFontMetrics`,

```
double stackMargins(const QList<double>& topMargins, const QList<double>& bottomMargins) {
    double total = topMargins[0] + bottomMargins[bottomMargins.size()-1];
    for(int i=1;i<topMargins.size();i++) {
        total += qMax(bottomMargins[i-1],topMargins[i]);
    }
    return total;
}

// assuming there are no spans within paragraphs and no images or tables or lists
QSizeF estimateSize(QTextDocument* doc) {
    double width = 0;
    double height = 0;
    QList<double> topMargings;
    QList<double> bottomMargins;
    QTextFrame* frame = doc->rootFrame();
    QTextFrameFormat frameFormat = frame->frameFormat();
    for (QTextBlock it = doc->begin(); it != doc->end(); it = it.next())
    {
        QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = it.blockFormat();
        QTextCharFormat charFormat = it.charFormat();
        QFontMetrics fontMetrics(charFormat.font());
        QStringList lines = it.text().split(QChar(QChar::LineSeparator));
        double frameMargins = frameFormat.leftMargin() + frameFormat.rightMargin();
        double blockMargins = blockFormat.leftMargin() + blockFormat.rightMargin();
        for(const QString& line: lines) {
            // there are more margins (needs more research)
            double extraSpace = 2;
            double lineWidth = fontMetrics.horizontalAdvance(line) + extraSpace + blockMargins + frameMargins;
            width = qMax(width, lineWidth);
        }
        height += fontMetrics.height() * lines.size();
        topMargings << blockFormat.topMargin();
        bottomMargins << blockFormat.bottomMargin();
    }
    height += stackMargins(topMargings, bottomMargins);
    return QSizeF(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `QTextDocument::size()` which works even if document was not rendered yet (although its not guaranteed that long lines wont get wrapped).

```
QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
QTextDocument* doc = new QTextDocument();
QString html =
        "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">"
        "<p style=\"color:red; font-family:'Courier New';\">Raw Header</p>"
        "<p style=\"font-family:'Courier New'\">00000000<br />00000000<br />00000000<br />00000000</p>"
        "</div>";
QTextOption textOption(Qt::AlignCenter);
doc->setDefaultTextOption(QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter)); // fixes center alignment in Qt4, not necessary in Qt5
doc->setHtml(html);
QSize size = doc->size().toSize() + QSize(2,2);
textEdit->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100,100), size));
textEdit->setReadOnly(true);
textEdit->setDocument(doc);
textEdit->show();
```